# Jekyll responsive_images gem throwing errors when trying to work with gh-pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, responsive-images

I've been working on my portfolio site using jekyll, and everything seems to work just great locally.  So, the next step for me was to push it up to github inside a gh-pages branch, and when I do that, I receive an email with the error below.

**The tag responsive_image on line 20 in _layouts/post.html is not a recognized Liquid tag.**

The gem that I'm trying to use is [Jekyll Responsive Images](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image).

Like I said before, when I run jekyll serve, I get no errors and I can run my jekyll site just fine locally, but for some reason this error is keeping my site from working with github.  My `post.html` file looks like this.

```
--- 
layout: default 
---
<article class="article--container">
  <header class="heading--articles">
    <h1 class="page-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="post-date">
      posted on {{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y"}}
    </p>
    {% if page.featured_image %}
    <div class="post-image">
      <img src="{{ page.featured_image }}" alt="{{ page.title }} featured image">
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>
  <div class="post--body">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
  {% if page.post_images %}
  <section class="post--images">
    <a href="http://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/patterns/images/fpo_landscape.png" class="box let-there-be-light">
      <span class="msg">Let there be light</span>
      {% responsive_image path: img/image.png alt: "Project Images" title: "Project Images"%}
    </a>
  </section>
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

In my _includes folder, I had to make a include for the responsive_images gem and it looks like this

```
{% capture srcset %}
    {% for i in resized %}
        /{{ i.path }} {{ i.width }}w,
    {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

<img src="/{{ path }}" srcset="{{ srcset | strip_newlines }} /{{ original.path }} {{ original.width }}w">
```

And here's my config.yml file for anyone wondering

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site settings
title: Portfolio
email: test@test.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"

baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://example.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: test
github_username:  test

permalink: /:categories/:title

links:
  - title: about
    url: /about
  - title: projects
    url: /projects
  - title: articles
    url: /articles

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown

gems:
  - octopress-autoprefixer

gems: [jekyll/responsive_image]

responsive_image:
  # [Required]
  # Path to the image template.
  template: _includes/responsive-image.html

  # [Optional, Default: 85]
  # Quality to use when resizing images.
  default_quality: 90

  # [Optional, Default: []]
  # An array of resize configuration objects. Each object must contain at least
  # a `width` value.
  sizes:
    - width: 350
      quality: 80
    - width: 480  # [Required] How wide the resized image will be.
      quality: 80 # [Optional] Overrides default_quality for this size.
    - width: 800
      quality: 90
    - width: 1400
      quality: 90

  # [Optional, Default: assets/resized/%{filename}-%{width}x%{height}.%{extension}]
  # The template used when generating filenames for resized images. Must be a
  # relative path.
  #
  # Parameters available are:
  #   %{basename}    Basename of the file (assets/some-file.jpg => some-file.jpg)
  #   %{filename}    Basename without the extension (assets/some-file.jpg => some-file)
  #   %{extension}   Extension of the file (assets/some-file.jpg => jpg)
  #   %{width}       Width of the resized image
  #   %{height}      Height of the resized image
  #
  output_path_format: img/resized/%{width}/%{filename}-%{width}x%{height}.%{extension}
```

Has anyone had this problem with the responsive images gem?  I can't seem to google an answer to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll responsive images is a Jekyll plugin and you cannot add your own plugins to github pages. This is a restriction by github due to security reasons.

[Here is the related page on github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/) and [here is the list of plugins that are officially included by github in the github server and can be used](https://pages.github.com/versions/).

You can try [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you're not allowed to use most of Jekyll plugins when hosting on GitHub for security reasons.

A good way out is uploading the static site generated by Jekyll, so GitHub won't build your site, it will only display it as plain html. To do that, the only thing you need to do is pushing to GitHub the `_site` content only.

Another way out is using GitLab Pages instead. There you can use as many plugins as you want, as the building process is controlled by yourself through a configuration file called `.gitlab-ci.yml`. A full tutorial on this process is to be published soon.

The only feature [GitLab.com](https://about.gitlab.com) doesn't have yet is the possibility of setting custom domain names for websites build by GitLab Pages. But it's coming soon.

Hope to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

***It is important to say that this is not a recommended way, but it works for me. I feel like the other answers were a bit to: No you can't - do this.***

Yes you can. But as Virtua Creative suggests - you need a workaround. Especially if you are using a custom domain.

I myself had problems with the [jekyll-responsive-image](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image) for resizing and lazy load on my Jekyll site.

It is **not** a supported gem.

### Example

First if all make your _site repository a git repository.

and remove CNAME from `.gitignore`.

When you are finished working locally then build:

`jekyll build`

Afterwords add a CNAME file to your build:

`touch _site/CNAME`

Echo your domain into it:

`echo 'www.your_domain.com' >> _site/CNAME`

And then you can push to your github pages repository (also from parent).

### Ekstra

Next time you can create a custom command in your bash to automate.

My .zshrc:

```
alias jekyll_build_cname='jekyll build && touch _site/CNAME && echo "www.instamoneyservices.de" >> _site/CNAME'
```

---